# Attacking hashed password by timing attack and other means

Tags: passwords, timing-attack

This question is inspired by this [recent one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14648/pbkdf2-password-validation), which raises a point that need to be made quantitative to be meaningfully discussed. I chose an unusual approach: a new question worded as homework that could be asked in a *computer security with applied cryptography* class (please use [meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/) for critics of that method).

Some system keeps track of user passwords as `(userID, H)` pairs with `H` of 20 octets and a single pair per `userID`. To test an alleged `Password` for some `userID`, it is checked that some `(userID, H)` exists; then computed `D` of 20 octets as
   `PBKDF2(PRF = HMAC-SHA-1, Password, Salt = userID, c = 10000, dkLen = 20)`;
then the alleged `Password` is accepted according to the C expression `memcmp(D, H, 20)==0`.
The value of `c` is 10 times what is described to *be a significant burden for opponents* in [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-3) defining `PBKDF2`.
The documentation of `memcmp`states:

> `int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);`
>
> The function compares successive elements from two arrays of unsigned
> char, beginning at the addresses `s1` and `s2` (both of size `n`), until
> it finds elements that are not equal:
>
> - If all elements are equal, the function returns zero.
> - If the differing element from s1 is greater than the element from s2, the function returns a positive number.
> - Otherwise, the function returns a negative number.

Assume than an adversary

1. can submit `(userID, Password)` pairs and determine if that's accepted or not, at a rate of $r\approx2^{10}$ pairs per second;
2. can at every such attempt measure the running time to fine accuracy, and consistently deduce how many elements have been compared in `memcmp`;
3. can perform `PBKDF2` at a rate of $h\approx 2^{40}$ per second (less computing power than devoted to bitcoin mining according to [this statistic](https://blockchain.info/en/charts/hash-rate?timespan=2year&scale=1));
4. does *not* initially know any `H`;
5. gets hold of $n\approx16$ target `userID`.

Give some approximation (as a function of the parameters) of the expected wall clock time since (5) for a competent adversary to find an acceptable `(userID, Password)` pair, without and with the insight given by (2), for these two models of choice of `Password`:

- uniformly at random among $2^b$ for $7\le b\le90$; detail the adversary's strategy when $b\approx44$ per [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/) recommendation;
- by user, with $u\approx 1/4$ of users having picked a password that occurs at least $5$ times in a list known to the attacker, comprising password choices assumed about representative of how actual users choose passwords, with statistics per these [2040 lines](http://hastebin.com/puhananapa.pl) of the form `a*b` (or just `a` when `b` is $1$), each line meaning that `b` distinct password choice(s) each occur `a` times in the list (note: the threshold of $5$ keeps $\approx50\%$ of the $32603388$ choices, and $\approx4\%$ of the $14344391$ distinct choices).

Propose C code for a `memneq` function, usable as replacement of `memcmp` where sign of its result is immaterial, and likely to close the timing vulnerability.

Outline standard techniques to dramatically improve security with no change of the current passwords.

Comment: The last link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make things slightly more abstract at first.

The attacker knows $n$ salts $s_i$. Passwords have $e$ bits of entropy and are hashed to $h_i = H(s_i, p_i)$. The attacker can calculate $2^c$ hashes $H(s_i, p)$ per second and can query some kind of an oracle $2^q$ times per second for the prefix length shared by $H(s_i, p)$ and the target $h_i$.

Simplest would be if the shared prefix length was known to the bit. In that case when the attacker knows the first $b$ bits of $h_i$, they can look for a $p$ for which $H(s_i, p)$ starts with those $b$ bits ($2^b$ work) and by querying the server would find an expected 2 more bits of $h_i$. Thus, finding the $e$-bit entropy password would take about $2^{e-1}$ hashing work and $e/2$ queries on average.

If the length is known with byte accuracy, the attacker would need to query up to 255 times to go from knowing $b$ bytes to knowing (usually) one more. The hashing work would remain the same at $2^{e-1}$, but about $128(e/8) = 16e$ queries would be required. With $w$-bit words, the number of queries required would be about $2^{w-1}e/w$.

So, in cracking those $n$ passwords, the attacker would spend $n2^{e-1-c}$ seconds hashing and $ne2^{w-1-q}/w$ seconds querying. With your numbers of $n=16$, $c=40$, $q=10$ and assuming $w=8$, cracking even 70-bit passwords would require less than half a minute of queries total, which means it is negligible compared to hashing time for anything remotely secure and the attack is effectively offline. Only with $w = 32$ and larger does it start to matter – each password would require a month or two of queries at that point.

With prefix queries at byte accuracy and 44-bit passwords, the attacker would require 8 seconds of hashing and less than a second of queries to crack all 16 passwords. They might be limited by network latency and need several extra seconds due to that.